# How do I fix this distorted output from guard when using guard-zeus?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec2, guard, zeus

I'm using the [`guard-zeus`](https://github.com/qnm/guard-zeus) gem in my application

The gem is behaving as expected, but the output to the console is all distorted.

It looks like extra tabs are being added, so the lines aren't breaking as they should

Anybody know how to fix this?

- zeus (0.15.1)
- guard-rspec (4.2.9)
- guard-zeus (2.0.0)
- guard (2.6.1)
- guard-livereload (2.2.0)
- rspec (2.99.0)
- rspec-collection_matchers (0.0.4)
- rspec-core (2.99.0)
- rspec-expectations (2.99.0)
- rspec-mocks (2.99.0)
- rspec-rails (2.99.0)

[image: My console output]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Zeus seems to interfere with normal console output, although I have no idea why. It also sometimes [hides what your typing](https://github.com/burke/zeus/issues/404) (which happened to me).

What resolved the issue for me (in a blank Rails 3 installation with the specified gems), was to use another ruby version (**2.0.0-p247** instead of **2.0.0-p353**), as [this related issue suggested](https://github.com/burke/zeus/issues/427).

It may be helpful to see the original Gemfile or rails setup, as this may be different for you and your specific setup.